# I want to find out the managers from the employee table

Tags: oracle11g

```
ENAME      JOB       DNAME                 MGR      EMPNO
---------- --------- -------------- ---------- ----------
CLARK      MANAGER   ACCOUNTING           7839       7782
KING       PRESIDENT ACCOUNTING                      7839
MILLER     CLERK     ACCOUNTING           7782       7934
JONES      MANAGER   RESEARCH             7839       7566
FORD       ANALYST   RESEARCH             7566       7902
ADAMS      CLERK     RESEARCH             7788       7876
SMITH      CLERK     RESEARCH             7902       7369
SCOTT      ANALYST   RESEARCH             7566       7788
WARD       SALESMAN  SALES                7698       7521
TURNER     SALESMAN  SALES                7698       7844
ALLEN      SALESMAN  SALES                7698       7499
JAMES      CLERK     SALES                7698       7900
BLAKE      MANAGER   SALES                7839       7698
MARTIN     SALESMAN SALES                 7698       7654
```

from the above table i want to find out the empname and their manager name from dept wise. 
i have two tables one is emp table and another table is dept by executing the below query i have brought the above result.

```
SQL> select ename, job, dname, mgr, empno 
     from emp e, dept d
     where d.deptno = e.deptno;
```

Comment: Yesterday somebody answer for my question but now it is not showing over here can someone answer for this question

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL> select e.ename emp_name, e.empno, e.job, m.ename mng_name,m.empno mng_empno
, dname from emp e, emp m, dept d where e.deptno = d.deptno and m.empno(+) = e.m
gr;
```